# NASM - Variable Basics

Tags: assembly, nasm

I know that you can create a string in nasm by writing this:

```
mystring db 'Hello World'
```

But if I want to move a single character, let's say e, the second character in the string to the al register. How can I do that? Should I write

```
mov al, mystring+1
```

or something? And how do I make an int variable? Can I write:

```
myint db 4
```

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/NASM_Syntax

Comment: You should read your NASM documentation. But an integer variable would be `myint dw 4` for a "word" or `myint dd 4` for a double word. `db` is a define *byte*. And `mov al, mystring+1` attempts to move the low byte of the *address* of `mystring`, plus 1, into `al`.

Comment: @lurker how can I give the byte a value then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'mystring + 1' is the address of the second byte of the string.

> mov al, mystring + 1

stores (the least significant byte of) that address in al. To indicate that you don't want to store the address but the byte located at that address, write this:

> mov al, [mystring + 1]

To declare a four-bytes integer equal to say, 42, use:

> myint dd 42

Comment: and how do I set a value to the integer?

Comment: Depending on your assembly flavor you could also say `mov al, byte ptr mystring+1`

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the OP's question is regarding NASM

Comment: @AntoineMathys I think you could be more specific about `mov al, string + 1` clearly stating that it stores the __truncated address__ of the second byte in AL.