# Why does + act differently for constants vs the rest of data types in x64 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, masm64

If I have a quad word named "a", this instruction: MOV RAX, a + 3 will offset the address of a by 3.

When i do the same thing with a constant (a EQU 10), MOV RAX, a + 3 will move into rax in binary the number 13.

Why does the cpu do that if it is the same "+" sign and the same MOV instruction ?

I wrote this code and while debugging I found out this strange thing. I just can t understand why and I can't find the answer online.

BTW I'm using MASM

Comment: That's your assembler, not the cpu.

Comment: Because a constant (EQU) doesn't have memory location.

Comment: But you might want to interpret it as an address, e.g. `vgamem EQU 0b8000h`. I believe masm requires the brackets then (or maybe a `qword ptr`).

Answer (score 2):

The CPU runs machine code, not asm source.

In MASM the same instruction syntax means different things in depending on whether it's a "variable" (symbol defined by a label) or an assemble-time constant (`equ` or `a = 10`).

Other assemblers (like NASM) don't have that inconsistency, so `mov rax, a+3` would always be a `mov rax, imm64` of an immediate constant, whether that's an address (link-time constant) or an assemble-time `equ` constant.  (In MASM, that would be `mov rax, OFFSET a+3`).

(NASM would actually optimize it to `mov eax, 13`, not 10-byte `mov r64,imm4`, but still a mov-immediate either way.)

---

**The inconsistency isn't in `+`, it always does addition.**
When `a` is a symbol / label attached to a `dq`, `a+3` is that symbol address plus three.
When `a` is an assemble-time constant defined with `equ` or `a = 10`, `a+3` is `10+3`.

A symbol's "value" is its address, like if you declared it in C as `extern char a[]`.  In MASM, if you did `dq a+3`, it would basically work the same whether it's a label or equ constant: add 3 to a link-time constant (address) or assemble-time constant (equ), and assemble those 8 bytes into the output file at the current position.

The inconsistency is in how operands to asm instructions work in MASM: see [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32)

- with or without square brackets, `mov rax, [a]` or `[a+3]` is a load from the address given by the expression `a` or `a+3`, if `a` is a label.
- But if `a` was an assemble-time constant, the instruction is a mov-immediate.

---

If you wanted to add to data being loaded from memory, like C `uint64_t tmp = a + 3;` where `a` is a global variable, you'd have to `mov rax, [a]` / `add rax, 3`.

But if `a` is a compile-time constant like C++ `static const uint64_t a = 10;` or `#define a 10`, then the compiler can do the addition at compile time, like `mov eax, 10+3` which assembles the same as `mov eax, 13`.

The only x86 instruction that can load something from memory and add to the load result is `add reg, [mem]`.  Like `mov eax, 3` / `add rax, [a]`.  (But that's less efficient than load+`add reg,imm`: larger code size and more back-end uops.)

(Intel's proposed [APX (Advanced Performance Extensions)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) will introduce EVEX encodings of integer instructions, making `add rax, [a], 3` possible, with a register destination separate from the two sources.)

---

**Any normal memory operand can use an addressing mode which can involve some address math, but address math is separate from math on data operands.**  Just like you can't do `mov rax, rcx + 3`, you need an `add` instruction to do math on values.  Or [an LEA to copy-and-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers).)  A different part of the CPU (the load/store execution units) handle address math like `[rdx + rcx*8 + 3]`, and it gets encoded differently in the machine code.

Perhaps *that*'s what you're thinking of as an inconsistency, if you're thinking of `a dq 10` as giving `a` the value `10` the same way `a equ 10` does.  It doesn't, it puts those bytes in data memory.  That's similar but different; the `10` isn't an assemble-time constant so you can use its value in expressions, and it's only accessible with load/store instructions.

BTW, `mov rax, a+3` doesn't involve any run-time address math, at least not for the `+3`.  The linker resolves `a+3` to a RIP-relative addressing mode just like with `a`, but offset by 3.  So for example it might be `[rip + 1013h]` for `a` vs. `[rip + 1016h]` for `a+3`.

---

PS: I mentioned NASM a few times as a point of comparison. See also:

- https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2
- [Why in NASM do we have to use square brackets ([ ]) to MOV to memory location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534661/why-in-nasm-do-we-have-to-use-square-brackets-to-mov-to-memory-location)
- [What's the difference between equ and db in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006711/whats-the-difference-between-equ-and-db-in-nasm)
- [how to get address of variable and dereference it in nasm x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534020/how-to-get-address-of-variable-and-dereference-it-in-nasm-x86-assembly) - note that MASM *does* use the term "variable" for things like `a dq 10` in a .data section, and it actually implies an operand-size when you use it like `add a, 1`.  Other assemblers don't have that high-level concept, they just have labels/symbols you can put before or after data, which you can use to implement static variables.